# How to scrape through pages when the url changes in multiples of 50?

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data. There are multiple pages, and the urls change by multiples of 50 like so:

```
http://myurl=0

http://myurl=50

http://myurl=100
```

This continues all the way to 950.

I am newish to webscraping and data science, and have been teaching myself, so don't understand all the concepts and possibilities. I am using python 3.7

So far I tried two different approaches

I tried to do something like this:

```
pages=[str(i) for i in range (0,20)]
for page in pages:
    my_url = 'http://myurl=' + (page*50)
```

But that didnt work.

I also tried to create a list of numbers and then loop through the list like this:

```
pages = list(range(0, 950, 50))
for page in pages:
    my_url = 'http://myurl=' + page
```

But that didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should get error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

That's because your variable `page` is an integer, and you're trying to concatenate to a string

try this

```
pages = list(range(0, 950, 50))
for page in pages:
    my_url = 'http://myurl=' + str(page)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Appreciate the help you have given me with other issues as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in several ways. Another of such might be:

```
my_url = 'http://myurl={}'
for link in [my_url.format(page) for page in range(0,950,50)]:
    print(link)
```